# Writing to GC Bucket using AppEngine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

The google docs states

> The GCS stream wrapper is built in to the run time, and is used when you supply a file name starting with gs://.

When I look into the `app.yaml`, I see where the runtime is selected. I have selected php runtime. However when I try to write to my bucket I get an error saying the wrapper is not found for `gs://`. But when I try to write to my bucket using the `helloworld.php` script that is provided by google here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld and modifying it so that it says

```
<?php
file_put_contents('gs://<app_id>.appspot.com/hello.txt', 'Hello');
```

I have to deploy the app in order for the write to be successful. I am not understanding why I have to deploy the app everytime to get the wrapper I need to write to my bucket. How come I can not write to my bucket from a random php script?

Answer (score 2):

Google says

> "In the Development Server, when a Google Cloud Storage URI is specified we emulate this functionality by reading and writing to temporary files on the user's local filesystem"

So, "gs://" is simulated locally - to actually write to GCS buckets using the stream wrapper, it has to run from App Engine itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$object_url = "gs://bucket/file.png";
$options = stream_context_create(['gs'=>['acl'=>'private', 'Content-Type' => 'image/png']]);
$my_file = fopen($object_url, 'w', false, $options);
fwrite($my_file, $file_data));
fclose($my_file);
```

Comment: This code works for me. 
I used it in app engine wordpress site and now I can save the logs in bucket files.
Thank you very much.